# How to get an element from an output in windows powersheell

Tags: powershell

I have an output like:

PS C:\Users\parul> $test2
id      label   region  type    image   status  ipv4
21648848        ubuntu-us-west  us-west g6-standard-1   linode/ubuntu20.04      offline 173.255.216.222

I need to get the id value only. How to i get this in powershell

Comment: Does `$test2.id` return desired content? If not, edit the question and show how `$test2` variable is assigned its content.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!)

Answer (score 0):

Please refine your question. If you are really asking for how to use properties a google search would've done the trick in under 1 minute.. To answer your question:

```
help about_Variables

$test2.id
```

Comment: Right, unless `$test2` is an array of strings instead of an object. Hard to say as the question doesn't contain details how the variable was assigned in the first hand.